# reading textile and adding to linked list in C

Tags: c, pointers, file-io, struct, linked-list

I'm trying to create a createLinkedListNode function in this program. In this function, I open a text file which is a parameter and I ask the user for the information in the employee struct and then i read it line by line from the file referenced in the file pointer. I add the data to a linked list. and i initialize that struct portion of the Linked list and set the next pointer to NULL and return a pointer to this newly created node. I have two structs, which confuses me because I don't know how i would add the data to the specified struct:

```
struct List{
    struct EMPLOYEE{
        int ID;
        char *fName[25];
        char *lName[35];
        double salary;
        char Location;
    }employee;
    struct List *next;
};
```

This is the main function where i have two linked lists, i don't have them initialized yet. but i call on the createLinkedList function in here and I call on the file pointer:

```
void main() {
    FILE *fp;
    struct List *onHead = NULL;
    struct List *offHead = NULL;

    createLinkedListNode();
}
```

I just get lost when it comes to reading the textfile line by line and adding the data accordingly. So if anyone can that will be great.

```
struct List *createLinkedListNode(FILE *fp, struct List *list, int ID, char fName, char lName, double salary, char Location){
    //This is the created node with its memory allocated.
    struct List* node = (struct List)*malloc(sizeof(struct List));

    fp =fopen("textfile.txt","r");

    //prompt for all info required in passenger struct
    printf("Enter Passenger ID:\n");
    fgets()
    node ->passenger.ID = ID;
    printf("Enter first name:\n");
    node ->passenger.fName = fName;
    printf("Enter last name:\n");
    node ->passenger.lName = lName;
    printf("Enter salary:\n");
    node ->passenger.CBalance= CBalance;

    printf("Enter location:\n");
    printf("1- on\n");
    printf("0- off\n");
    node ->passenger.Location =Location;

    node ->next = list;
    return node;
}
```

Lets say the textile being read is something like this:

```
0001
John
Tyler 
23.00
1
0002
Erin
Marc
25.00
0
0003
Jason
Ed
15.00
1
```

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing. 1. Are you meaning to read the student data from a file or to prompt the user for it? You seem to be implying both at the same time. 2. What are the two linked lists supposed to represent? 3. Your call to `createLinkedListNode` doesn't match the definition (missing parameters and ignored return value). 4. What is your specific question? You need to be more specific than "it doesn't work".

Comment: 1) the data is read only from the file,not from the user.  the questions are just there so you can see each line being read individually. 2)the two linked lists are used later on, if the employees location is 1, he is added to the onHead List, and if their location is 0, he is added to the offHead List. 3) I didn't know if the parameters i had in the function were correct yet so i left that blank for now. 4) my specific question is how would i read this data from the file and add it to the struct and the linked list and create this node so that it can be used later on.

Answer (score 1):

I dont't really understand the issue you have, but it looks like some informations about fgets would help you ^^ Just so you see how fgets works:

```
char buffer[100];
FILE *fp = fopen("textfile.txt","r");

while (fgets(buffer, 100, fp)) {
    printf("%s", buffer);
}
```

This would print your whole file line by line. Each call to *fgets* stores the next line of your file in the string passed in the first parameter (second param is the maximum amount of char you can read, and last one is your file)

*fgets* return null when you reached the end of the file, that's how this while works.

So instead of printing after each *fgets* you can compute the line and fill your struct, you will have to convert string to integer/double tho.

**EDIT:** Well here are spoilers of how to fill your struct, it's not the ideal solution because it should be more robust, like handeling cases where the file is not like you expect, but it will probably helps you.

Also I think something is wrong in your struct, you write:

```
    char *fName[25];
    char *lName[35];
```

This would create you an array of 25/35 char*, I think you want that without the * so it's simply an array of 25/35 char (which is a char*)

**SPOILERS!!!** So here i wrote a little C file which read your textfile and print the list to show it works, and as I said it have to be improved to be used in a serious soft, file may not be like we want for instance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct List{
    struct EMPLOYEE{
        int ID;
        char fName[25];
        char lName[35];
        double salary;
        char location;
    }employee;
    struct List *next;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char buffer[100];
    struct List* node = NULL;

    FILE *fp = fopen("textfile.txt","r");

    printf("Reading file....\n");

    while (fgets(buffer, 100, fp)) {
        // File is not empty, it should at least contain a full employee
        struct List* new_node = malloc(sizeof(struct List));
        new_node->next = NULL;

        // ID
        new_node->employee.ID = atoi(buffer);

        // fName
        fgets(buffer, 25, fp);
        int l = strlen(buffer);
        if (l > 0 && buffer[l-1] == '\n') buffer[l-1] = '\0'; // We dont want the \n in the name ^^
        strcpy(new_node->employee.fName, buffer);

        // lName
        fgets(buffer, 35, fp);
        l = strlen(buffer);
        if (l > 0 && buffer[l-1] == '\n') buffer[l-1] = '\0'; // We dont want the \n in the name ^^
        strcpy(new_node->employee.lName, buffer);

        // salary
        fgets(buffer, 100, fp);
        new_node->employee.salary = atof(buffer);

        // Location
        fgets(buffer, 100, fp);
        new_node->employee.location = buffer[0];

        // We add to the list
        if (node == NULL) {
            node = new_node;
        } else {
            new_node->next = node;
            node = new_node;
        }
    }

    printf("We're done\n");

    while (node != NULL) {
        printf("Employee:\n");
        printf("  ID:\t\t%i\n", node->employee.ID);
        printf("  fName:\t%s\n", node->employee.fName);
        printf("  lName:\t%s\n", node->employee.lName);
        printf("  Salary:\t%f\n", node->employee.salary);
        printf("  location:\t%c\n\n", node->employee.location);
        node = node->next;
    }

    // Memory leaks fest :)
    return 0;
}
```

Also last thing, if there is no particular reason you named the location with a big L, you should call it *location*

Tell me if something is wrong ^^